# VLC bash transcoding script output to file

Tags: bash, audio, linux-mint, vlc-media-player, transcode

I'm running such script to transcode my audio files:

```
#!/bin/bash
acodec="vorb"  
arate="256" 
ext="ogg" 
vlc="/usr/bin/vlc" 
fmt="mp3" 

for a in *$fmt; do 
$vlc -I dummy -vvv "$a" --sout "#transcode{acodec=$acodec,ab=$arate,channels=2}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=\"$a.$ext\"}" vlc://quit 
done
```

And trying to redirect this script output to file like this:

```
./transcode.sh > /media/sf_Downloads/transcode.log
```

But receive only 0 byte file. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC is writing to `stderr` and not `stdout`. You can mend this in your log redirection by calling the script like:

```
./transcode.sh > /media/sf_Downloads/transcode.log 2>&1
```

or in the Bash specific way:

```
./transcode.sh &> /media/sf_Downloads/transcode.log
```

You can also do the redirection to `stdout` within the script by adding `2>&1` at the end of the line with the VLC command within the loop. Then you can call the script just as you tried before:

```
./transcode.sh > /media/sf_Downloads/transcode.log
```

and get the intended logging result directly.

For more information, see e.g.

- [Chapter 20. I/O Redirection [TLDP]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)
- [Redirect stderr and stdout in a bash script [SO]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637827/445621)